# Using Kubernetes javascript client inside a deployment to create a job

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

Hi i created a node app that creates a k8s job with kubernetes-client library. Then that job app responds back with a HTTP call to my node app. to reduce network latency and timing, i have to put everything inside a cluster. Is this possible to create a job inside a deployment?

References: https://github.com/kubernetes-client

```
   apiVersion: batch/v1
   kind: Job
   metadata:
     name: job
   spec:
     ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 10
     template:
       spec:
         containers:
         - name: samplejob
           image: gcr.io/hjgfjfhgffghfght
           command: ["node",  "index.js", '{api_url":"apienpoint"}']
           resources:
             limits:
               memory: "128Mi"
               cpu: "100m"
             requests:
               memory: "128Mi"
               cpu: "100m"
         restartPolicy: Never
     backoffLimit: 1
```

Comment: what you wanna achieve ? Deployment will likely keep the pods running (provided the logic written that way) and jobs/cronjobs are written to carry out a task at specific points of time.

Comment: I want to create a job inside my node app and that node app should also run in same cluster

Comment: If your looking for an option to create Pods that run multiple containers that need to work together, then you might need to refer [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#understanding-pods) help center article. I am not sure whether this will satisfies your need, but worth to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible. It all depends on how you create your node.js container image. Your application can run as a deployment within the cluster. Something will cause the application to trigger an event. That event will send an API call to the k8s master to request that a job be created.

You can use one of the [client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) to interface with the k8s master. The node.js library is maintained by the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can build docker image for your code, like you can use

```
node server.js
```

to trigger your main application and place the same image in the Kubernetes job, keep that in some other directory and execute that using the

```
command
```

option in the yaml template of job/cronjob.

This will sort it for you

Comment: No, my problem is i want to create a job from a pod